# In Laravel can you establish a relationship between models based on fields that are not keys

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have three models: `Vehicle`, `LiveData`, and `Place`.

In my `Vehicle` model, I currently have a relationship between `Vehicle` and `LiveData` that gets the latest `LiveData` for a vehicle:

```
public function latestPosition(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(LiveData::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```

Now in my `LiveData` model, I want to establish a relationship between `LiveData` and `Place`, however there are no direct keys between the two, the relationship is between a range of latitude and longitude.
This is how the relationship would be called in pure sql:

```sql
LEFT JOIN `places`
    ON `live_data`.`speed` = 0 AND `places`.`lat` BETWEEN (`live_data`.`lat` - 0.00007) AND (`live_data`.`lat` + 0.00007) AND `places`.`lng` BETWEEN (`live_data`.`lng` - 0.00007) AND (`live_data`.`lng` + 0.00007)
```

Because I want to be able to use this relationship with eloquent like so:

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::where('disabled', 0)
    ->with(['latestPosition.place', 'tags'])
    ->get();
```

Is this something that is even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

**Yes**, you can establish eloquent relationships with fields that are not keys.

For example, for tables such as these

```
+-------+   +----------+
| users |   | profiles |
+-------+   +----------+
| id    |   | ...      |
| email |   | email    |
| ...   |   | ...      |
+-------+   +----------+
```

You could define a `hasOne` or `belongsTo` using email as instead of a key. Foreign keys are not a requirement. They just make it easier to keep data integrity and your rdbms knows how to optimize queries for them a bit.

```php
function profile() { return $this->hasOne(Profile::class, 'email', 'email');
```

**No**, you cannot define a relationship that does that exact query in the background. Not unless you were to implement a custom `Relation` class. Laravel does not provide (to my knowledge) any relationship that resolves to a `LEFT JOIN` clause that compares columns to values or aggregate values.

You could define a query scope that encapsulates all that logic on the `LiveData` model and then call that.

I use `$join->where` instead of `$join->on` because `on` is reserved for comparing columns whereas `where` can be used to compare with values.

```
// LiveData
public function scopeWithPlace(Builder $query)
{
    return $query->leftJoin('places', function (JoinClause $join) {
        $join->where('live_data.speed', 0)
            ->whereRaw('places.lat BETWEEN (live_data.lat - ?) AND (live_data.lat + ?)', [0.00007, 0.00007])
            ->whereRaw('places.lng BETWEEN (live_data.lng - ?) AND (live_data.lng + ?)', [0.00007, 0.00007])
    })
    ->addSelect('places.*');
}
```

```php
$vehicles = Vehicle::query()
    ->where('disabled', 0)
    ->with([
        'latestPosition' => fn ($liveData) => $liveData->withPlace(),
        'tags'
    ])
    ->get();
```

Comment: The join seems to be there however the query selects only `live_data`.* so when I dd($vehicle) I dont have anything from my places table

Comment: What if you add `->addSelect('places.*')`to the query scope?

Comment: It it now in the query but how do I access it? When I dd($vehicles) and I go in the item of the first vehicle then relations > latestPosition I dont see a further relations with places or any traces of them, however I know theyre in the query.

Comment: oh I see they were injected directly in the latestPosition, is there a way to have them outside so within a loop of my vehicles I could do $vehicle->latestPosition->place to get them?

Comment: Because it's not a relation.All the `places` column data should be in the same place as the `live_data`. If you have columns with the same name in both tables, you are going to need to specify some aliases in the select. `->addSelect('places.lat as places_lat', 'places.lng as places_lng')

Comment: There is no immediate way. If `$vehicle->latestPosition` returns a collection, you could then use the collection's `groupBy` method to do that in your loops.